# TFS 2010 Get Changeset Details from Branch to Branch

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I would like to be able to supply a changeset from branch-2 and get the changesets that were merged up from branch-1.  I have tried QueryHistory but have been unable to get any type of history.   This functionality would be the same as the Tracking Changeset in VS 2010.   This is needed by the release mgmt team to cross check approved changeset thru the lifecyle.

Answer (score 0):

what you are after is the "tf merges" command;
you should use it as 
 tf merges branch-1 branch-2 /recursive